# Pass a list from python to flask so that it will not show in the html

Tags: javascript, python

I saw many answers on how to pass a list from python to flask. All of them suggest to pass it as a variable on the render_template.
For example

```
render_template('map.html', trends=trends)
```

And then on the flask template get it using

```
{{ trends | safe }}
```

The problem with this solution is that once someone opens the source of the html, the list is shown.

**I DO NOT want the list to show.**

In my case the list consists of hundreds of elements and it is ugly and not elegant.

The list will be used in the the java script part of the html.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered putting it inside a script block? Something along the lines of `<script> myVariable = {{ trends | safe }}; </script>`

Comment: That is what I am doing now **seats_json = JSON.parse('{{ seats|tojson }}');** inside my script and it shows the data

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, it might help someone else @Zvi

Comment: My comment explained that the problem is not solved. I posted my question because using the above code shows the data on the source of the HTML page and I do not want it to be part of the HTML page. My comment was to answer @Seon that what he suggested is wrong.. I guess he did not test his advice.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it is by using an ajax to get the data from the app